# Mismatch in custom post type permalink and post url in address bar

Tags: php, wordpress, permalinks

Been putting pieces of different tutorials as the need arises. Unfortunately am stuck. I created a custom post type successfully and added posts also successfully. Unfortunately I messed with the permalinks somehow and the url of one of the custom post type should be this and so is the permalink. //localhost/wordpress/team_slider/eddard-stark/
But
The url in address bar in my browser is:  //localhost/wordpress/team_slider/eddard-stark/eddard-stark/

Not sure how this came up.

```
//registered the custom post type
function stellar_law_custom_post_types () {
    //members_slide_custom_type
    $labels_team = array (
        'name' => 'Team slider',
        'siingular_name' => 'Team Slider Content',
        'add_new' => 'Add member Slide',
        'all_items' => 'Team members Slides',
        'add_new_item' => 'Add Member Slide',
        'edit_item' => 'Edit Member Slide',
        'new_item' => 'New  Member',
        'view_item' => 'View Member Slide',
        'search_item' => 'Search Team Slides',
        'not_found' => 'No slides found',
        'not_found_in_trash' => 'No slides found in trash',
        'parent_item_colon' => 'Parent Item'
    );`enter code here`
    $args_team = array (
        'labels' => $labels_team,
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => false,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'supports' => array(
            'title',
            'editor',
            'excerpt',
            'thumbnail',
            'custom-fields',
            'revisions'
        ),
        'taxonomies' => array('category', 'post_tag'),
        'menu_position' => 103,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-images-alt',
        'exclude_from_search' => false
    );
    register_post_type('team_slider', $args_team);
}
add_action('init', 'stellar_law_custom_post_types');


//displaying articles in wordpress loop
<section id="dream-team">
                <div class="dream-team-slider">
                    <?php
                    $team_sliders_args =  array(
                        'post_type' => 'team_slider',
                        'orderby' => 'menu_order',
                        'order' => 'ASC'
                    );
                    $team_sliders_query = new WP_Query( $team_sliders_args );
                    while ($team_sliders_query->have_posts()) : $team_sliders_query->the_post();
                    ?>
                        <div class="member">
                            <div class="memberImage">
                                <?php
                                    $team_slider_image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
                                    $team_slider_image_url_array = wp_get_attachment_image_src($team_slider_image_id, 'full');
                                    /*returned as array(url, width, height, is_intermediate)*/
                                    $team_slider_image_url = $team_slider_image_url_array[0];
                                ?>
                                <div id="image-placeholder"
                                     style="background-image: url('<?php echo($team_slider_image_url);?>');
                                            background-repeat: no-repeat;
                                            background-position: center;
                                            background-size: cover;"></div>
                                <div class="member-info">
                                    <div>
                                        <h3><?php the_excerpt(); ?></h3>
                                        <a class="button" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="member-intro">
                                    <div>
                                        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                                        <?php
                                            $team_slider_post_id = get_the_ID();
                                            $member_role = get_post_meta($team_slider_post_id, 'Position', true);
                                        ?>
                                        <h5><?php echo $member_role;  ?></h5>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                </div>
            </section>
```

The permalink setting is set to post name
http://localhost/wordpress/sample-post/

Comment: can you share your code ?.so that someone can answer it

Comment: you could do a string replace for post_name in permalink so that you remove the post_name plus the trailing / and make it so it get's stripped out.